# exceeds dimension bound Error reading netcdf with fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, netcdf

I am a user who uses Fortran.
I try to get the average value after reading netCDF using Fortran, but I get an error

```
PROGRAM net1
        use netcdf

        IMPLICIT NONE

        CHARACTER(len = 256) :: fi
        REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: T2(:,:,:)

        INTEGER :: dx, dy
        INTEGER :: ncid, varid
        INTEGER :: start(3), count(3)


        fi = "wrfout_d01_2016-10-06_00.nc"
        dx = 209
        dy = 209

        call check(nf90_open(fi, NF90_NOWRITE, ncid), "opening T2 file")
        call check(nf90_inq_varid(ncid, "T2", varid), "getting T2 varid")

        allocate(T2(1, dx, dy))
        start = [1, 1, 1]
        count   = [0, dx, dy]

        WRITE(*, *) "Reading Grid T2"
        call check(nf90_get_var(ncid, varid, T2, start = start, count = count), "reading T2")
        WRITE(*, *) "Mean T2 : ", sum(T2) / size(T2)

        call check(nf90_close(ncid), "closing T2 file")
        deallocate(T2)

        contains
                SUBROUTINE check(status, loc)
                        INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: status
                        CHARACTER(len = *), INTENT(in) :: loc

                        if(status /= NF90_NOERR) then
                                WRITE(*, *) "Error at ", loc
                                WRITE(*, *) NF90_STRERROR(status)
                        end if
                        END SUBROUTINE check
END PROGRAM



Reading Grid T2
 Error at reading T2
 NetCDF: Start+count exceeds dimension bound
 Mean T2 :    0.00000000
```

The first one is my code, and the second one is an error

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 T2(Time, south_north, west_east)
    FieldType: 104
    MemoryOrder: XY 
    description: TEMP at 2 M
    units: K
    stagger: 
    coordinates: XLONG XLAT XTIME
unlimited dimensions: Time
current shape = (1, 209, 209)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

As a result of reading using Python, the dimension of T2 is (1, 209, 209), but I don't know if this error occurs
Obviously, the same error occurs even though I set it to 209.

Comment: I'm not a netcdf expert but that count looks wrong to me - you are saying you want to read 0 * dx * dy = 0 values. What happens if you cahnge the 0 to 1?